# wp_get_current_user() and is_user_logged_in() in child theme's functions.php file don't work

Tags: child-theme

Is there any reason why `wp_get_current_user()` doesn't return the logged in user's info array when used within *functions.php* file in a child theme, nor does the `is_user_logged_in()` return the correct state for a logged in user? They both return `0` regardless if the user is logged in or not.

I am embedding the wordpress libraries into a 3rd party script and everything, literally everything else works outside of wordpress on a separate PHP page but this.

Comment: What's your WP version?

Comment: Latest one available.

Comment: From which action/filter are you calling them?

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to a hook firing sequence issue.  When are you hooking your function?

The safest way to detect your current user is to fire on [wp_login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) action.  Someone [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004757/get-current-user-id-not-working-with-wp-login-hook-wordpress) the need to call it late.

The codex recommends to use [wp_get_current_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) functon on or after the `init` hook.